# Finding the smallest element of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, minimum

I'm 10th grade student, only 2 weeks of coding. I have a homework to fix this code if not working from the book with the title "Finding the smallest element of a vector". I've been stuck here over 5 days, and tomorrow is my due date.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, T[10], int min;
    for (i = 10; i < 10; i = i + 1)
        cin >> T[i];
    min = T[0];

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        if (T[i] < min)
            min = T[i];

    cout << "Min= " << min;
    return 0;
}
```

What should I change in order to work? Thank you.

Comment: What have you learned using your debugger?

Comment: This is a good time to run your program under a debugger and step through every line. See Eric Lippert's article on [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for approaches if you get stuck.

Comment: In particular, you have a very obvious typo that I believe is causing all your problems.

Comment: Not to mention that the first line of main does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two lines wrong: `int i, T[10], int min;` and `for (i = 10; i < 10; i = i + 1)`. Here is a working [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lX2VzkYbazvfJRyC).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, T[10], min;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 1)
        cin >> T[i];
    min = T[0];
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        if (T[i] < min)
            min = T[i];
    cout << "Min = " << min;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this one is totally correct, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the first for you should go from i = 0, not i = 10.

Comment: I just tried, the compiler just says "compiling" and then nothing... [the code in compiler](http://cpp.sh/7wdh7)

Comment: It's waiting for *you* to say something. That's what `cin` does.

Comment: I typed, it stood froze and didn't do anything

Comment: @DeividMiço just press on the run and it will say program running. A cursor would be blinking in execution panel. Where you have to enter 10 numbers and hit enter. Enter these for example: `5 6 2 8 1 0 9 3 7 3`. See this video: https://imgur.com/a/Czdo4wV.